# How make 3 different textbox same height (in responsive state)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap V3.3.5. Screen divided in 3 columns horizontal.
Each column has different text length that can be **changed by user**.

Columns are responsive horizontal (by Bootstrap).

Goal... how to fix: I want **same height** for those 3 columns -boxes. Each columns-box must have the height of highest column-box.... so all column-boxes have same height.

Except....in Bootstrap "xs" mode, boxes are vertical (there is no problem).
Problem is in "sm, md and lg" mode (Bootstrap) when columns are horizontally next to each other.

EDIT:

I thought the problem was in the **text**, but it seems to be in the button of a bootstrap **MODAL** ... so I had not place the modal code in the first code.

I did: place `style="white-space: normal;"` (to fit text in modal) - seems there is a conflict with this style

Wanted:

- Modal **buttons height** the same in bootstrap sm, md, lg mode (height of largest button)
- Text begin at same height
- Text fit in button

See snippet in Full-page mode!

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.row {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.row {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- BootsTrap V 3.3.5 -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row RowHeight" >
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_1" style="white-space: normal;">
  Launch demo modal 11 11 111 111
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel_1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel_1">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  </div><!-- col2 -->
<!-- Button trigger modal (end) -->

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_2" style="white-space: normal;">
  Launch demo modal 2222 222 222 222 222 222 222  22222222 22 22222 2222
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel_2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel_2">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  </div><!-- col2 -->
<!-- Button trigger modal (end) -->

  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flexbox` to achieve it, you can easily have the same height for all `.box` based on the max height column, I made a short example based on your code, take a look:

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.row{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- BootsTrap V 3.3.5 -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" >
    <!-- for test! -->
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 box">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 box">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing consec elit.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 box">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipis cing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa cing.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .box {
    min-height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <!-- for test! -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="box">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="box">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing consec elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="box">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipis cing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa cing.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u add this on your `onload` function `

```
var heighest = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].offsetHeight;

for(i = 1;i<3; i++){
    if(heighest < document.getElementsByClassName("box")[i].offsetHeight){
      heighest  = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[i].offsetHeight;
    }
}`
```

After that u can use `heighest`

```
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: heighest;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to assign a hardcoded height to your "box" class,  based on your highest column-box, for example:

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Other solution could be calculating your highest column box height via JavaScript and assign the same height to the other 2 boxes dynamically, also via JS.